# Get all column values in pairs for each row in a DataFrame without using zip

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe

```py
print(df)

a | b | c
--+---+---
1  20   30
2  200  300
3  2000 3000
```

I can create a list with all elements from each row like

```py
for a,b,c in zip(df["a"],df["b"],df["c"]):
 function_using_them(a,b,c)
```

My question is - isn't there a way to do this with less code/faster, since we already have all the elements stored in the rows in the dataframe, something like

```py
for a,b,c in df.get_row_values():
 function_using_them(a,b,c)
```

Comment: why not simply use ```iterrows``` or ```itertuples``` and then use indexing?

Comment: why not use ```df.apply(function_using_them, axis=1)```? it is faster

Comment: `df.agg(list,1)`? Is that all you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for `df.to_records`. This will output a NumPy ndarray with the DataFrame labels as fields and each row of the DataFrame as entries. The labels can be omitted with `index=False`:

```
df.to_records(index=False)
```

Result `list(df.to_records(index=False))`:

```
[(1, 20, 30), (2, 200, 300), (3, 2000, 3000)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Spoilt for choice.

Either

```
`df.agg(list,1)`
```

Or

```
df.agg(list,1).sum()
```

or

```
df.agg(tuple,1).tolist()
```